# Can event sourcing and standard repositories be mixed?

Tags: axon

In [Axon](https://axoniq.io), can I configure a different repository per aggregate type? Some of my aggregates may be event sourced, while it makes no sense for others if there's no need for auditing or restoration to an earlier state.

In the [documentation about repositories and event stores](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/1.3-infrastructure-components/repository-and-event-store), it says to implement the interface `Repository<T>`, which binds to a specific type of aggregate.

```
/**
 * The repository provides an abstraction of the storage of aggregates.
 *
 * @param <T> The type of aggregate this repository stores.
 */
public interface Repository<T> extends ScopeAware
```

Which leads me to believe that I can implement a `Repository<Car>`, `Repository<Garage>` and so on which may or may not be event sourcing, annotate them with Spring's `@Repository` and I'm good to go. Is that the case?

I'm aware that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44661084/1704311) exists, however the answer just states:

> you can only use a single Repository to load an Aggregate.

This doesn't clarify whether a single repository is bound to all aggregates, or to one aggregate type.

#### Set Validation

As a side question, will using a [Standard Repository](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/1.3-infrastructure-components/repository-and-event-store#standard-repositories) as opposed to an [Event Sourcing Repository](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/1.3-infrastructure-components/repository-and-event-store#event-sourcing-repositories) alleviate the problem of [uniqueness constraint checking in CQRS](http://danielwhittaker.me/2017/10/09/handle-set-based-consistency-validation-cqrs/)? When storing the state of an aggregate (in contrast to just events), I could define uniqueness constrains in the underlying persistence storage. Upon commit, the command should fail and no events should be dispatched. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application can very well both have the, what's internally called, `GenericeJpaRepository` and the `EventSourcingRepository` along side one another. What you can't do however, is have both repositories for a single Aggregate implementation.

Luckily I see that that's what you're looking for, different ways of storing *different* aggregates. How to configure this depends on one thing though. If you are in a Spring environment, simply annotating your state-store Aggregate with JPA annotations is sufficient. If you omit these JPA annotations, it will automatically default to being an Event Sourced Aggregate.
If you are not using Spring however, you can configure this by using the `AggregateConfigurer#jpaMappedConfiguration` for state-stored Aggregates and `AggregateConfigurer#defaultConfiguration` for the Event Sourcing approach.

Simply put though, you very likely do not have to implement your own `Repository`. Sorry to hear the documentation led you to believe this was the case, I'll ensure we'll adjust that.

In regards to your set validation question, I am not sure to call it 'solving the problem' more as to moving it to the database layer. As the article you share suggests, that is one of the solution to solve the problem, but it comes at a price.

Comment: That's great. Don't worry, the docs didn't lead me to believe that I **must** implement my own repositories for this to work. I want to use a persistence storage that is not yet supported anyway, for which I intend to implement an `EventStorageEngine` and possibly custom repositories. Using Spring, but no JPA. How would I tell Axon to use my (non event sourcing) repository for my aggregate? Does the `@Repository` annotation suffice? Also, will a failed commit to the repository (write-store) make a command fail and cancel all events as expected? Thanks for your valuable information.

Comment: The `AggregateConfiguer` also has a function to register you own Repository for a given Aggregate Type. I suggest you have a look at it's API to find out all the option you have in regards to configuring an Aggregate instance :-)